# StackOverflowError during build room

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room

I'm trying to use room and write this:

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = arrayOf(ForeignKey(entity = Category::class, 
parentColumns = arrayOf("id"), childColumns = arrayOf("parentId"))))
data class Category (
    val type: Byte,

    val name: String,

    val description: String,

    var parentId: Long? = null,

    var remoteId: Long? = null,

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0L,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "parentId")
    var subcategories: List<Category>? = null
)
```

But i got this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details
```

and more details:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: 
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
```

Maybe somebody face this problem (because without subcategories field all works good).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `@Relation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation):

> Note that `@Relation` annotation can be used only in Pojo classes, an Entity class cannot have relations.

Ideally, you would get a better build error than the `StackOverflowError`, but you should get a build error of some form.